# Identification of plant growing on Grange-over-Sands promenade, in organised flower bed

Tags: identification

Plant growing adjacent to the sea, so salt tolerant. Dense, ground cover type plant. Longish, ovate leaves, central spine to leaf. Leaves green, central spine whiteish. Flowers on red stem stand above the leaves. Newer flowers are spiked, multi petalled, whitish pink. Later flowers seem to turn red and look dried deep red.(similar shape to catkins)

Comment: Where does the plant grow?

Comment: @kevinsky: I think the title reference to Grange-over-Sands is a location in Cumbria (NW England).

Answer (score 2):

[*Persicaria affinis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persicaria_affinis), maybe [*P. affinis* 'Donald Lownes'](http://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/60308/Knotweed-Donald-Lowndes/Details)? Otherwise need a photo. By Grange-over-Sands, I'm assuming you mean Cumbria.